# Differentiable curves on $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, spheres

Is it true that for every differentiable curve $\gamma:(a,b)\to S^2$ parametrized by arc length, we have $\|\gamma''(t)\| \geq 1$ for every $t\in (a,b)$?.

I want to know if this is correct:

Let $II_p$ denote the second fundamental form at the point $p$ and $N_p$ the Gauss map at the point $p$. Then we have $dN_p = Id$ for every $p$ in $S^2$ since the surface we consider is $S^2$. Therefore, for $t \in (a, b)$, we have $-1 = -\|\gamma'(t)\|^2 = -\langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)\rangle = -\langle dN_{\gamma(t)}[\gamma'(t)], \gamma'(t)\rangle = II_{\gamma(t)}[\gamma'(t)] = \langle N(\gamma(t)), \gamma''(t)\rangle$.

Thus, $1 = |\langle N(\gamma(t)), \gamma''(t)\rangle| \leq \|N(\gamma(t))\| \cdot \|\gamma''(t)\| = \|\gamma''(t)\|$, where I used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and $\|N(\gamma(t))\| = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very direct proof using only basic calculus:

From $\|\gamma\|^2=1$ we get by differentiating $0=\gamma'\cdot \gamma$ and
$0=\gamma''\cdot\gamma+\|\gamma'\|^2\,.$ Since $\gamma$ is parametrized by arc length we know that $\|\gamma'\|=1\,.$ So we have
$$
|\gamma''\cdot\gamma|=1\,.
$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
|\gamma''\cdot\gamma|^2\le \|\gamma''\|\underbrace{\|\gamma\|}_{=1}
$$
and your claim follows.

Comment: Ok, its another interesting demostration, but my demostration is ok?

Comment: @Andreadel1988 It is pretty much the same proof but for another audience. You may want to elaborate how you go from $II_{\gamma(t)}[\gamma'(t)]$ to $\langle N(\gamma(t)), \gamma''(t)\rangle\,.$

Comment: i use that $\gamma'(t)$ and $N(\gamma(t))$ are orthogonal and the i derivate $<\gamma'(t),N(\gamma(t))>=0$ in $t$

Comment: Which was exactly what I also used. The merit of your approach is to see Gauss map, Weingarten map and second fundamental form in action in a very transparent example. Nice post.

Comment: oh thanks, i appreciate